# Sql Delete Multiple Data at Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

We use the code below to show the data in our mysql tables..

```
"SELECT products.productName, images.url FROM products, images 
WHERE products.id='23'
AND images.productID='23';"
```

My question is this :

is it possible to delete from multiple tables, do you have an idea how to do it or must we delete the data one at a time ?

```
"DELETE FROM products, images WHERE images.productID='23' AND products.id='23'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following

```
DELETE  products, images
FROM products INNER JOIN images
ON  images.productID=products.id and products.id='23'
```

Comment: im waiting the timer :)

Comment: DELETE c, d,g, i, o, p, pr, t FROM comments c, discounts d, products p, productid pr, images i, gifts g, onecikan o, tags t WHERE i.productID='359' AND p.id='359' AND c.productID='359' AND d.productID='359' AND g.productID='359' AND o.productID='359' AND pr.productID='359' AND t.productID='359' I have a problem. if in comments table dont have 359 its not delete other tables.. how can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
DELETE p, i
    FROM products p, images i
    WHERE i.productID='23' AND p.id='23'
```

The aliases aren't strictly necessary but they make the query easier to read and write.

Comment: DELETE c, d,g, i, o, p, pr, t
    FROM comments c, discounts d, products p, productid pr, images i, gifts g, onecikan o, tags t
    WHERE i.productID='359' AND p.id='359'  AND c.productID='359' AND d.productID='359' AND g.productID='359' AND o.productID='359' AND pr.productID='359' AND t.productID='359'

I have a problem. if in comments table dont have 359 its not delete other tables.. how can I make it?

Comment: This is a downside to deleting from multiple tables.  You had already accepted the other answer, so I didn't elaborate on this.  I would recommend that you just do multiple deletes in separate statements.